# Unable to find reasonable kubernetes installation documentation

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have been trying to setup kubernetes for a week now as part of an evaluation, but I can only find

- extremely complex manual solutions that are already out of date or outright broken
- insanely simple solutions that break a mind numbing amount of best practices
- "get to know kubernetes cluster all on one box"

My base requirements going in are:

1. I have AWS
2. I have VPCs, Subnets + peering already created
3. I need to be able to build one cluster per environment in the appropriate VPC
4. Ubuntu 16.04
5. I should have control over the SGs and instances (terraform + ansible)
6. Absolutely no single points of failure.
7. I don't want a solution that creates unnecessary layers by adding tools or controllers above the masters. (WHY?!!)
8. No blatant security holes

I've tried a couple solutions, but they have failed spectacularly, and require #7

kubeadm (breaks #6, #7)

- I gave this a try because it was supposed to be a reasonable solution for using existing infrastructure.
- I was able to get a cluster operational with 1 master and 2 nodes, but it just didn't seem to be working fully (kubernetes-dashboard was inaccessible)
- In the end, even the tool itself didn't recommend production due to the fact that the docs state the master node cannot be made HA.

juju / conjure-up with "canonical kubernetes" (breaks #2, #3, #5, #6, #7, #8)

- did not allow specification of VPC.  Nevermind managing SGs, instances, working via bastion host.
- It actually created instances in ec2-classic...?
- instance naming in AWS is awful (can't tell what's what - masters vs etcd vs ??)
- 15 security groups for a 3 worker cluster, 9 of which are completely empty?
- conjure-down fails with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'controller'
- It created a single point of failure in the "controller machine"
- INGRESS TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0 <- I am going to cry (this is why ec2-classic went away years ago)

Comment: This is much more of a rant than a question.

Comment: https://github.com/lowescott/2017-itx-container-workshop?files=1

Answer (score 1):

Try out [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) - it has support for [Terraform output](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/terraform.md). It should be possible to meet your other requirements with it (although some, like no single point of failure, may require changing the default config).

Answer (score 0):

You can check [typhoon](https://typhoon.psdn.io/aws/). Personally I'm using [kube-aws](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws) which is more flexible, but unfortunately no terraform.

I also created a [quick start](https://github.com/camilb/kube-aws-secure) script based on `kube-aws`.